# Using OptaPlanner to solve large Vehicle Routing case

Tags: optaplanner

I have 4 people to visit 22.000 places. So, I need to minimize the total time of the visits.

I have the spatial location of the places, and I'm thinking of getting a distance between them or using euclidian distance or using the Google Maps API.

It's possible to solve this problem using OptaPlanner.

I think of solving using the Vehicle Routing modeling. This is the best option? Would OptaPlanner support this amount of input data?

Answer (score 0):

OptaPlanner has done cases like this, but you'll need to enable "nearby selection" explicitly because it's above 1k locations.

Because it's above 10k locations, it might be interesting to benchmark (using the benchmarker) with Partitioned Search too. For example, to speed up the Construction Heuristic, you might want to wrap that in a Partitioned Search. You probably can't wrap it all, because there are only 4 people.

As for using Google Maps API, [first read this blog](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/09/02/VehicleRoutingWithRealRoadDistances.html). Then: 10k locations takes 2GB of RAM IIRC to store the distance matrix in its most efficient form (double array of 32-bits) - this has nothing to do with optaplanner. I suspect 22k will bring you near 10GB of RAM just to load that in memory.